# Different sample rate SR for same wav file between librosa and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, wav, librosa

I have one wav file which I resampled to 16.000 kHz with Audacity.
Now I am trying to load the file with python with 2 different ways.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import librosa

f = "path/to/wav/file/xxxx.wav"

raw = tf.io.read_file(f)
audio, sr = tf.audio.decode_wav(raw, desired_channels=1)
print("Sample Rate TF: ",sr.numpy())

y, sr2 = librosa.load(f)
print("Sample Rate librosa: ",sr2)


#Sample Rate TF:  16000
#Sample Ratelibrosa:  22050
```

Why is the sample rate so different for the same file?
Which library I can trust more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a question of "trust". Both functions do what they are supposed to do. The TF version apparently does not resample the audio. Librosa, by default, resamples to 22,050 Hz (for whatever reason). Please [read the docs](https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.0/generated/librosa.load.html#librosa.load). You can avoid this by calling

```
y, sr2 = librosa.load(f, sr=None)
```

In general, the `sr` argument provides the sampling rate to resample to; by passing `None`, you prevent resampling.

Comment: Oh, that was a great hint. Thanks!